# Change keyboard shortcuts in Cinnamon does not work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, cinnamon

Changing a keyboard shortcut does in cinnamon settings menu does not work. I've got two shortcuts (from default configuration) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> which I'd like to remove.

Removing them in the System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Windows (where they are) does not seem to work.

Any help/ideas? Perhaps changing them manually in the conf files, where should I look?

Comment: I've managed to get this to work by overwriting the same actions over and over with different key shortcuts until finally setting an empty key shortcut worked.
So I guess its more of a bug in cinnamon than a question.
If anyone wants to debug - use Super+L key combination to start cinnamon debugger.

Comment: This worked for me in Linux Mint 17.2, I've opened an issue https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that this was in fact a bug in Cinnamon. It looks like it's closed:  https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4777

Closing the question. Thanks @henrik-lindgren

Answer (score 2):

I tried many options but only one worked under Cinnamon. Run applet  keyboard and go to shortcuts/windows/positioniong and select "Move window". Instead of deleting this shortcut just assign a new one, alt-f3 for example. It works fine for me, in opposition deleting shortcut does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @wojtek-wirzbicki, but this is not exactly what I need. I want to remove the shortcut and I was wondering maybe I did something wrong. But it seems it might be a bug in cinnamon.

Comment: I found replacing the shortcut the only way to disable it. I switched the shortcut binding I wanted to delete to another shortcut that's available but doesn't conflict with anything. I changed `Alt + F7/F8` to be `Super + F7/F8` so that I could use `Alt + F7/F8` in IntelliJ IDEA the way I'm used to. Obviously not as friendly as removing the binding entirely, but worked for what I needed to do.